# TechGraph: A landscape of a tag/tech in Stack Overflow

Tags: app, website, search

### Screenshot

[image]

### Update

**Version 0.1**

- Right-click to see the tagWiki (there was a collision between single click and double click);
- Add one section (ExpertGraph) to show the expertise graph of experts who have earned more than 3,000 reputation scores before March 8th, 2015 in Stack Overflow. Some experts are not shown as their answer number is insufficient to generate an expertise graph;
- Adjust the UI layout;
- Add one "beta" icon from testing applications.

**Version 0.2**

- Add a new function that users can look up top-upvoted questions for the given tag;
- Add a new function that users can look up tag-related external links which is mined from post content from Stack Overflow;
- For some tags, you can also find related code snippets mined from tagWiki and [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code);
- Speed up the page loading by optimizing both front-end and back-end code.

**Version 0.3**

- Extract the tag category label from tag wiki in Stack Overflow;
- Discriminate the library/API/toolkit from the knowledge graph and put them aside the knowledge graph in the website so that users can have a clearer view.

**Version 0.4**

- Get more categorizations of tags and then list them aside the knowledge graph.
- Update author information.

### About

This is a website providing an overview/landscape of certain tech (tag) in Stack Overflow. You can explore this site to enrich your knowledge and refine what you need.

Given a tech (tag), the website can render:

- its definition from tagwiki;
- its asking trend in Stack Overflow;
- its knowledge graph i.e., visualizing related tech and their relationships in an interactive graph so that you can have an overview of it;
- experts of it with their knowledge graphs rather than a list of tags (experts are selected by reputation score and whether their answer number is enough to generate knowledge graph).

Given multiple tech/tags, they will be compared in both asking trend and knowledge graph.

In addition, you can also specify a task and a programming language to see a knowledge graph which may provide some hints or solutions to the tasks.

### Website

Our website can be visited in https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/

### License

The Service is still in construction and more functions will be added in the future. All are free.

### Contact

For any questions, bugs, suggestions, please leave a message in this post or contact me in my email chen0966@e.ntu.edu.sg

Comment: Sah-weet! Looks promising.  But the "Top Answerers" display does not match SO's "All Time" Answerer lists.  See, for example, [the Greasemonkey top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey/topusers).

Comment: @BrockAdams This website is not updated in real time because it will take too much time to load the page. So we now use the rank list when we built the site. But it will updated maybe monthly. Of course, real-time system will be the final one.

Comment: Understood, but ErikVold hasn't been in the top 3 for that tag for many years (if ever).  Either the app's initial data is years old, or something else is occurring. ;)

Comment: PS, real-time is dirt simple, at least for determining top answerers.  See [the API's ` /tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags).  All you need is a `GET` request and an optional API key to increase your app's quota.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. But the process to generate the answerer's knowledge graph is quite time-consuming (Get the data--> find his answers --> get tags of questions of his answers --> generate knowledge graph).

Comment: With the question rate graph, how about some way of also showing the question rate in relation to the overall question rate. i.e. in the graph above, d3.js question rate went down last year, but did it globally?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, Good suggestions and I will try to add more. Thanks.